# Email Address Generator

Tags: smtp, freebsd, email

I'm developing a service which requires me to generate a new email for every "sign up." For example, person000@name.com, person001@name.com, person002@name.com, and so forth. My first attempt was creating a gmail account and doing a person+000@gmail.com thing, but when I send the email and make the "From" address to "person+000@gmail.com" the google email server changes it to without the +000.
Oh and when someone emails any of the email addresses, they all go to the same email account (ie person@name.com). If anyone knows of an email server for FreeBSD that can do this, please let me know!

Comment: It's quite unclear what the problem is that you're trying to solve. Are you trying to allow sending via an arbitrary email address through a gmail server?

Comment: this is what i want to do: i want to send an email from an account person@name.com with an alias of person001@name.com (personXXX@name.com), and when the recipient responds to "person001@name.com" it goes to the person@name.com account. idc how i achieve this :P

Comment: How are you sending the messages?  I highly doubt Google would actually change the 'from' on an incoming message.  Are you sure you are setting both from fields?

Comment: @Zored: his problem is when he *sends* the email through Google, they change the From address to what his account is allowed to use. Google does this to prevent spoofing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Use the `email+localpart@domain.com` as the From address, just don't send it through Google. This is the simplest way and requires no further configuration. Sendmail (and others) support this out of the box.

Google requires that you verify each email address that you want to send From, to prevent spoofing. This is why it's changing your From address.

Comment: sweet thanks! didn't know the +local was widely supported.